# Magnetic field existence - a relativistic approach

Tags: electromagnetism, relativity

Recently I learnt that magnetic force is equal to relativistic electrostatic force. With this approach I was able to understand the motion of a charged particle kept near a current carrying conductor.

Now my question is - Usually when we suddenly stop the current in a conductor a surge in magnetic field occurs. But I am not able to understand this phenomenon with the relativistic approach. When we stop the current electrons slows down and instantly the magnetic field should disappear , this is not the case. What mistake am I making??

Comment: I don't know if this answers your question, but I think that you are forgetting that the electromagnetic's field reaction to a variation in the state of motion of the charges is retarded, so the magnetic field should not disappear instantly.

Comment: @GiorgioComitini: But how does spike in magnetic field occurs.

Comment: I'm not able to give an answer in full detail, but if the charges are brought to a sudden stop, their deceleration has dramatic effects on the electromagnetic field. If you have a look at the Maxwell equation containing the current term, you will see that a non-stationary current will produce complicated changes in the field. I don't think that the study of such a case can be reduced to a discussion in principle.

Comment: I think you have the wrong intuition about the phenomenology. When you stop the current flow, there is no surge in the magnetic field. What will happen is that the field will start to decay, which causes an electric self-induction field, which will try to keep the current flowing. This electric field can become very high, but the magnetic field will inevitably become smaller. That this has to happen is a consequence of energy conservation. The magnetic field energy has to go somewhere. If it can't be used to keep the charge carriers flowing, then it will convert into an electric field.

Comment: @CuriousOne: Thnx for clearing the doubt. I spent 1 week finding answer to question. If you have, could you please provide me a link explaining how electric field is generated from magnetic field in the same approach(relativity) mentioned in the question.

Comment: There is no need for a relativistic approach as nothing is moving relative to the coil. The speed of the electrons in the wire doesn't matter, it would be on the order of fractions of a mm/s. You can solve Maxwell's equations in the rest system of the coil and this will give the correct solution. What does move, if you are asking about relativistic velocities, is the electromagnetic field that gets emitted by this magnetic coil antenna.

Comment: @CuriousOne: Please suggest some book for advanced electromagnetism or recommend some electromagnetism books. I am reading electromagnetism just because of my interest. My professional work/world has no relation with electromagnetism.

Comment: I am generally against book recommendations. How much someone is getting out of any book is a function of that person, not a function of the book. As far as electromagnetism is concerned, you can probably find almost everything about the theory on the internet, it's just a matter of wanting to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maxwell by itself doesn't say that there is a particular electric or magnetic field due to charges or currents. Maxwell requires you fix boundary conditions as well as charges and currents before you can solve for electric or magnetic fields.

Now if you have *initial* fields and you have currents, then you could use Maxwell to find out how the fields evolve in time. In which case things change by:

$$\frac{\partial B}{\partial t}=-\vec \nabla \times \vec E$$ and

$$\frac{\partial E}{\partial t}=\frac{1}{\epsilon_0}\left(-\vec J +\frac{1}{\mu_0}\vec \nabla \times \vec B\right).$$

And with this approach, both the fields (electric *and* magnetic) are real and have their own values and the electric field tells you how the magnetic field changes, and the imbalance between the magnetic field and the current tells you how the electric field changes.

And this works fine if you already know the initial fields and you know the current. And it works even for electromagnetic waves propagating in empty space, and this is simply what Maxwell says.

But if you want to talk about fields due to charges and currents, there are examples such as [Jefimenko's equations:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jefimenko%27s_equations)

$$\vec E(\vec r,t)=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\int\left[\frac{\rho(\vec r',t_r)}{|\vec r -\vec r'|}+\frac{\partial \rho(\vec r',t_r)}{c\partial t}\right]\frac{\vec r -\vec r'}{|\vec r -\vec r'|^2}
-\frac{1}{|\vec r-\vec r'|c}\frac{\partial  \vec J(\vec r',t_r)}{c\partial t}\mathbb{d}^3\vec r'$$ and
$$\vec B(\vec r,t)=\frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\int\left[\frac{\vec J(\vec r',t_r)}{|\vec r -\vec r'|^3}+\frac{1}{|\vec r -\vec r'|^2}\frac{\partial \vec J(\vec r',t_r)}{c\partial t}\right]\times(\vec r -\vec r')\mathbb{d}^3\vec r'$$
where $t_r$ is actually a function of $\vec r'$, specifically $t_r=t-\frac{|\vec r-\vec r'|}{c}.$

These reduce to Coulomb and Biot-Savart only when those time derivatives are exactly zero, which is statics. So Jefimenko is an example of proper time dependent laws for the electromagnetic field. Note that *both* the electric and the magnetic part of the electromagnetic field have parts that depend on the time variation of current.

So when the current changes at place-time $(\vec r_1,t_1)$, there is an electric and a magnetic field. But the field exists only at place-times $(\vec r_2,t_2)$ where $t_2=t_1+\frac{|\vec r_2-\vec r_1|}{c}$.

So when the current changes, there is a spherical shell that expands at the speed $c$ and on that shell there is both an electric and a magnetic field.

And sure, if you want forces, and you use the Lorentz Force then all you need is the electric field in the instantaneously comoving frame of the charge. So you can ignore the magnetic field to compute forces with the Lorentz Force if you are willing to change frames every instant.